# i want to rotate image in center point only of the image and rotation tools stick on top left to image

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, kineticjs, image-rotation

i'm using Kineticjs to make tools in canvas to resize it or rotate
but when i try to rotate it tool drag away of it and image have a wrong rotate
chick the link of my code

http://jsfiddle.net/vipmaa/qFmsM/3/

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
function randomInt(min,max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-(min+1))+(min+1));
    }
//try to use
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: 'stage',
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
        offsetX:30,
        offsetY:30
    });
function update(activeAnchor) {
        var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

        var RotateSign = group.get('.RotateSign')[0];
        var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
        var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
        var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
        var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];
        var mask = group.get('.mask')[0];

        var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
        var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();

        // update anchor positions
        switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
            case 'RotateSign':
                var radius = mask.getWidth() * mask.getScale().x + 55;
                group.rotate(radius);

                break;
            case 'topLeft':
                topRight.setY(anchorY);
                bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'topRight':
                topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                RotateSign.setY(anchorY);
                break;
            case 'bottomRight':
                bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                topRight.setX(anchorX);
                break;
            case 'bottomLeft':
                bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                RotateSign.setX(anchorX);
                break;
        }

        mask.setPosition(topLeft.getPosition());

        var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
        var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();
        if (width && height && (width > 1 && height > 1)) {
            mask.setSize(width, height);
        }
    }

function addAnchor(group, x, y, name) {
        var layer = group.getLayer();
        var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            stroke: '#666',
            fill: '#ddd',
            strokeWidth: 2,
            radius: 8,
            name: name,
            draggable: true,
            dragOnTop: false
        });

        anchor.on('dragmove', function () {
            update(this);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
            group.setDraggable(false);
            this.moveToTop();
        });
        anchor.on('dragend', function () {
            group.setDraggable(true);
            layer.draw();
            update(this);
        });
        // add hover styling
        anchor.on('mouseover', function () {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            this.setStrokeWidth(4);
            layer.draw();
        });
        anchor.on('mouseout', function () {
            var layer = this.getLayer();
            document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            this.setStrokeWidth(2);
            layer.draw();
        });

        group.add(anchor);
        if(name == 'topLeft'){
            anchor.hide();
        }
    }
function init(){
  var rand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100087600);
        var id = $(this).attr('data-name')+'_'+rand;
        var config = {
            id : 'canvas_'+id,
            draggable:true,
            name: 'art'
        }
        var x =randomInt(0,100);
        var y =randomInt(0,100);

        var artGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
            x: x,
            y: y,
            name:'Group',
            draggable: true
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer(config);
        var imageObj = new Image();
        imageObj.onload = function() {

            var yoda = new Kinetic.Image({
              x: x,
              y: y,
              image: imageObj,
              width: imageObj.width,
              height: imageObj.height,
              name: 'mask',
            });
            // add the shape to the layer
            artGroup.add(yoda);
            layer.add(artGroup);
            // add the layer to the stage
            stage.add(layer);

            addAnchor(artGroup, x, y, 'topLeft');// it will be hide
            addAnchor(artGroup, (x + imageObj.width), y, 'topRight');
            addAnchor(artGroup, (x + imageObj.width), (y + imageObj.height), 'bottomRight');
            addAnchor(artGroup, x, (y + imageObj.height), 'bottomLeft');

            //Start add rotation tools
            var sign = new Kinetic.Path({
                name:'RotateSign',
                x: x, y: y,
                // Path from http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-path-tutorial/
                data: 'M12.582,9.551C3.251,16.237,0.921,29.021,7.08,38.564l-2.36,1.689l4.893,2.262l4.893,2.262l-0.568-5.36l-0.567-5.359l-2.365,1.694c-4.657-7.375-2.83-17.185,4.352-22.33c7.451-5.338,17.817-3.625,23.156,3.824c5.337,7.449,3.625,17.813-3.821,23.152l2.857,3.988c9.617-6.893,11.827-20.277,4.935-29.896C35.591,4.87,22.204,2.658,12.582,9.551z',
                scale: 0.4, fill: 'black',
                offset:25,
                dragOnTop: false,
                draggable: true
              });
            sign.on('dragmove', function () {
                update(this);
                layer.draw();
            });
            sign.on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
                //artGroup.setDraggable(false);
                //this.moveToTop();
            });
            sign.on('dragend', function () {
                //artGroup.setDraggable(true);
                layer.draw();
                update(this);
            });
            artGroup.add (sign);
            //End add rotation tools
            artGroup.on('dragstart', function () {
                this.moveToTop();
            });
            artGroup.on('dragmove', function() {
                var img = layer.get('.mask');
            });
            layer.on('mouseover', function () {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
            });
            layer.on('mouseout', function () {
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            });
            stage.draw();  
            };
        imageObj.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/images/w3logotest2.png";
   };
init();});
```

i want to rotate around image and tool stick in image
can you know what is wrong in the code

Comment: Maybe i ask wrong question i want to rotate image in center point only and rotation tools stick on top left to image

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the below,

```
  function update(activeAnchor) {
            var group = activeAnchor.getParent();

            var topLeft = group.get('.topLeft')[0];
            var topRight = group.get('.topRight')[0];
            var bottomRight = group.get('.bottomRight')[0];
            var bottomLeft = group.get('.bottomLeft')[0];

            var rotateAnchor = group.get('.rotateAnchor')[0];
            var image = group.get('Image')[0];

            var anchorX = activeAnchor.getX();
            var anchorY = activeAnchor.getY();
            var imageWidth = image.getWidth();
            var imageHeight = image.getHeight();

            // update anchor positions
            switch (activeAnchor.getName()) {
                case 'rotateAnchor':

                    break;
                case 'topLeft':
                    topRight.setY(anchorY);
                    bottomLeft.setX(anchorX);
                    break;
                case 'topRight':
                    topLeft.setY(anchorY);
                    bottomRight.setX(anchorX);
                    break;
                case 'bottomRight':
                    topRight.setX(anchorX);
                    bottomLeft.setY(anchorY);
                    break;
                case 'bottomLeft':
                    topLeft.setX(anchorX);
                    bottomRight.setY(anchorY);
                    break;
            }

            if (topRight.getX() < topLeft.getX() + minImgSize) {
                topRight.setX(topLeft.getX() + minImgSize);
            }
            if (bottomRight.getX() < topLeft.getX() + minImgSize) {
                bottomRight.setX(topLeft.getX() + minImgSize);
            }
            if (bottomRight.getY() < topLeft.getY() + minImgSize) {
                bottomRight.setY(topLeft.getY() + minImgSize);
            }
            if (bottomLeft.getY() < topLeft.getY() + minImgSize) {
                bottomLeft.setY(topLeft.getY() + minImgSize);
            }

            var width = topRight.getX() - topLeft.getX();
            var height = bottomLeft.getY() - topLeft.getY();

            image.setPosition({
                x: topLeft.getPosition().x,
                y: (topLeft.getPosition().y)
            });
            image.setWidth(width);
            image.setHeight(height);

            rotateAnchor.setX(width / 2 + topLeft.getX());
            rotateAnchor.setY(height / 2 + topLeft.getY());

        }

  function addAnchor(group, x, y, name, dragBound) {
            var stage = group.getStage();
            var layer = group.getLayer();
            var groupPos = group.getPosition();



            var anchor = new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: x,
                y: y,
                stroke: '#666',
                fill: '#ddd',
                strokeWidth: 2,
                radius: 6,
                //name: name,
                id :"anchor",
                name:name,
                draggable: true,
                dragOnTop: false
            });


            if (dragBound == 'rotate') {
                startAngle = angle(groupPos.x, groupPos.y, x + groupPos.x, y + groupPos.y);

                anchor.setAttrs({
                    dragBoundFunc: function (pos) {
                        return getRotatingAnchorBounds(pos, group);
                    }
                });
            }


            anchor.on('dragmove', function () {
                update(this);
                stage.draw();
            });
            anchor.on('mousedown touchstart', function () {
                group.setDraggable(false);
                this.moveToTop();
            });
            anchor.on('dragend', function () {
                group.setDraggable(true);
                stage.draw();
            });
            // add hover styling
            anchor.on('mouseover', function () {

                var layer = this.getLayer();
                document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
                this.setStrokeWidth(4);
                stage.draw();
            });
            anchor.on('mouseout', function () {
                var layer = this.getLayer();
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
                this.setStrokeWidth(2);
                stage.draw();
            });

            group.add(anchor);


        }

  function loadImages(sources, callback) {
    var images = {};
    var loadedImages = 0;
    var numImages = 0;
    for(var src in sources) {
      numImages++;
    }
    for(var src in sources) {
      images[src] = new Image();
      images[src].onload = function() {
        if(++loadedImages >= numImages) {
          callback(images);
        }
      };
      images[src].src = sources[src];
    }
  }
  function radians(degrees) {
            return degrees * (Math.PI / 180)
        }

        function degrees(radians) {
            return radians * (180 / Math.PI)
        }

        function angle(cx, cy, px, py) {
            var x = cx - px;
            var y = cy - py;
            return Math.atan2(-y, -x)
        }

        function distance(p1x, p1y, p2x, p2y) {
            return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p2x - p1x), 2) + Math.pow((p2y - p1y), 2))
        }

        function getRotatingAnchorBounds(pos, group) {
            var groupPos = group.getPosition();
            var rotation = degrees(angle(groupPos.x, groupPos.y, pos.x, pos.y) - startAngle);
            var dis = distance(groupPos.x, groupPos.y, pos.x, pos.y);
            console.log('x: ' + pos.x + '; y: ' + pos.y + '; rotation: ' + rotation + '; distance:' + dis);
            group.setRotationDeg(rotation);
            return pos;
        }
  function initStage(images) {
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 578,
      height: 400
    });
    var darthVaderGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: 270,
      y: 100,
      draggable: true
    });
    var yodaGroup = new Kinetic.Group({
      x: 100,
      y: 110,
      draggable: true
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

    /*
     * go ahead and add the groups
     * to the layer and the layer to the
     * stage so that the groups have knowledge
     * of its layer and stage
     */
    layer.add(darthVaderGroup);
    layer.add(yodaGroup);
    stage.add(layer);

    // darth vader
    var darthVaderImg = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: images.darthVader,
      width: 200,
      height: 138,
      name: 'image'
    });

    darthVaderGroup.add(darthVaderImg);
   addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, 0, 'topLeft', 'none');
            addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, darthVaderImg.getWidth(), 0, 'topRight', 'none');
            addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, darthVaderImg.getWidth(), darthVaderImg.getHeight(), 'bottomRight', 'none');
            addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, 0, darthVaderImg.getHeight(), 'bottomLeft', 'none');
            addAnchor(darthVaderGroup, darthVaderImg.getWidth() / 2, darthVaderImg.getHeight() / 2, 'rotateAnchor', 'rotate');

    darthVaderGroup.on('dragstart', function() {
      this.moveToTop();
    });
    stage.draw();
  }

  var sources = {
    darthVader: 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg'
  };
  loadImages(sources, initStage);
```

Check http://jsfiddle.net/Qnil/XR7vL/
KineticJS is best to handle rotate image and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

i found new canvas library (Fabric.js) it is solve all things i ask before

you can see blow link
[Fabric JS](http://fabricjs.com/controls-customization/)

You  can see different in rendering time

[fabricjs vs kineticjs](http://jsperf.com/fabricjs-vs-kineticjs)